# Magento 2 :Get country code from Country Name

Tags: magento2, factory

I have the country name with me. How can I get corresponding country code from it.
For ex: If the country name is Unites States, I want to get country code from it ie, US

If there any way for it?

I found many useful links for getting country name from country code. I want it in the reverse manner.

```
   public function __construct(
            \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory
        ) {
            $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
        }

    public function getCountryname($countryCode){    
        $country = $this->_countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($countryCode)
        echo $country->getName();
    }
```

Comment: can you give code which you are using

Comment: Please upload code or give file path where you want to get?

Comment: I have a custom custroller and reading the country name from from a csv

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot  to add semicolon after `$country = $this->_countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($countryCode)`

Add code in your controller :

```
protected $_country;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Directory\Model\Country $country
) {
    $this->_country = $country;
}

public function getCountryname() {
    $countryName = "Your country name";
    $countryCollection = $this->_country->getCollection();
    foreach ($countryCollection as $country) {
       if ($countryName == $country->getName()) {
          $countryId = $country->getCountryId();
          break;
       }
    }
    echo $countryId;
}
```

**remove generated folder and clean cache.**

Comment: I want to get country code from country name. Please read my question carefully.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I update answer right now.

Comment: Check it now...

Comment: Please accept answer so it will helpful for other developer also :)

Comment: Happy to help !! Happy Coding :)